# Multiple select in Thymeleaf doesn't store chosen options

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to learn Spring and other related technologies during summer break by developing a simple web application, however Thymeleaf hinders my progress.

The program is based on two entity classes:

Invoice.java:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    private String invoiceId;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate issueDate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

TrasportOrder.java:

```
@Entity
public class TransportOrder {

    @Id
    private int number;

    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal value;

    @ManyToOne
    private Invoice invoice;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm getting a form for adding invoices using a method from InvoiceController:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/add")
public String getForm(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("unusedOrders", service.getInvoiceOrders(null));
     model.addAttribute("orders", new ArrayList<TransportOrder>());
     model.addAttribute("invoice", new Invoice());

     return "addInvoice";
}
```

*unusedOrders* is a list of orders that a user can choose from,
*orders* is a list that is meant to contain orders chosen by user
*invoice* is just an invoice that's being created in the form.

My form contains text and data inputs regarding the invoice, and then comes a multiple select for the orders:

```
<!-- I used to define th:object here and used th:field in the inputs, however changed it to use th:value everywhere -->
<form action="/invoices/add" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Invoice ID:
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" th:value="${invoice.invoiceId}" name="invoiceId"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- a few other inputs -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Orders:
                </th>
                <th>
                    <!-- problem may lie here -->
                    <select id="orders" th:value="${orders}" multiple="multiple">
                        <option th:each="unusedOrder: ${unusedOrders}"
                                th:value="${unusedOrder.number}"
                                th:text="${unusedOrder}">Unused orders to choose from</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Next</button>
    </form>
```

I've read Thymeleaf docs and forums, as well as several SO questions, but they still leave me confused about how does `th:object`, `th:field`, `th:value` and others work with forms, and especially with multiple `select` tag.

On submit, the form sends a POST request to a method in the same controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add")
public String addInvoice(@ModelAttribute Invoice invoice,
                         BindingResult result,
                         @ModelAttribute("orders") ArrayList<TransportOrder> orders,
                         Model model) {

    //invoice and orders saving logic, etc.

    return "viewInvoices";
}
```

My problem is that `invoice` is being properly retrieved from the from and persisted in the database, but `orders` list stays empty. **I expect it to be populated with orders chosen in the form.** I don't know, if it's because of `@ModelAttribute` annotation (I also tried `@RequestAttribute` without success), Thymeleaf tags, or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I decided to fight for the answer once more, and fortunately I stumbled upon an answer.

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list), I created an wrapper class `ChosenOrdersDTO`:

```
public class ChosenOrdersDTO {
    private List<TransportOrder> chosenOrders;

    //constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

I added it to the first model (changed the `getForm()` method as following):

```
model.addAttribute("chosenOrders", new ChosenOrdersDTO(new ArrayList<>()));
```

In the form I used the `th:field` tag, similarly to previous fields:

```
<select id="orders" th:field="${chosenOrders.chosenOrders}" multiple="multiple">
```

And in the second controller I was able to retrieve the list wrapped in the `ChosenOrdersDTO` class as a `@ModelAttribute`:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add")
public String addInvoice(@ModelAttribute Invoice invoice,
                          BindingResult
                         @ModelAttribute ChosenOrdersDTO chosenOrders,
                          Model model)
```